# Создание иерархии Exceptions для формулы

Tags: исключения, java

На курсах учитель дал нам задание создать какие то свои `Exceptions`, создать какую-то их иерархию. Но вопрос не в этом. Он дал нам формулу `(((a+b)+(b+a))*c/)d`  - это все числа. Так вот эти все мои `Exceptions` должны быть созданы для этой формулы. Подскажите, каким образом так сказать прилепить эти исключения к этой формуле. Просто в голову ничего не приходит. То есть при работе формулы нужно ловить свои исключения. Но где там может быть что-то схожие на хоть какие-то исключения не могу понять. Я надеюсь, вопрос понятен)

Answer (score 2):

Немного непонятно по самой формуле:
*c/)d, если здесь символ "/" - деление, то деление на что?
Это как раз может стать Вашим исключением - на 0 делить нельзя.
В процессе вычисления по этой формуле, например, будете проверять, чтобы делитель не равнялся 0, иначе генерируйте своё собственное исключение.

Answer (score 2):

Exception существует не только для того, чтобы ловить ошибки, но также для того, чтобы исключать заведомо нежелательные результаты или значения переменных.
Таким образом, для данного уравнения можно написать, что определенные значения каждой переменной будут выбрасывать определенный вид Exception. Я полагаю в этом и состоит Ваше задание?!

Comment: Именно в этом. Просто наш лектор любит, чтобы все было как он говорит красиво и интересно. А выбрасывать ошибки при некоторых значениях ему наверное не очень понравится)

Comment: Вам предложено данное задание в учебных целях - научиться пользоваться Exceptions? Возможно это будет некрасиво в данном случае, но интересно же :))

Answer (score 0):

банальный пример:

```
class ArithmeticException extends Exception {...} // общий предок
class ParseExpressionException extends ArithmeticException {...} // синтаксическая ошибка в формуле
class AddException extends ArithmeticException {...} // ошибки для каждой операции
class SubException extends ArithmeticException {...}
class MultException extends ArithmeticException {...}
class DivException extends ArithmeticException {...}
class ZeroDivException extends DivException {...} // частный случай ошибки при делении
```